# How to create TTL Index on long timestamp in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, nosql

In my mongo database I have field timestamp which holds time of creation in timestamp ie: `"timestamp": 1544029233021`
I want to create TTL index on this field, but in docs example is done on `"createdAt": new Date(),` which is `ISODate("2018-12-13T17:00:10.433Z")`

Is it possible to in any way to make TTL Index work on timestamp field?

Because this doesnt work:

```
db.coll.createIndex( { "timestamp": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 3600 } )
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documents aren't being expired because the `timestamp` value is an integer.

TTL indexes will only work on documents where the indexed field is a Date or holds an array of Dates:

> If the indexed field in a document is not a date or an array that
>   holds a date value(s), the document will not expire.

(https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, MongoDB supports TTL indexes on fields containing epoch time, represented as long integers.

You can create a TTL index on a field containing epoch time directly without needing to convert it to a date object. It must be there in newer versions of MongoDB.