# Comparing mongodb timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hey guys i have used mongoose schema for my docuements where i have used timestamps to get the exact date and time of document but now what i want is i want to delete this docuements after 10 mins so how do i compare this documents timestamp

> 2020-04-16T09:23:22.938+00:00

with

> 10 mins

I need to do is : query over this document and if timestamps has been greater than 10 mins i need to delete this documents so i need to somehow compare this timestamps with "10 mins" and this is also stored in my documents under the field "task duration" entered by user with the help of form in frontend side

Comment: So you wanted to delete documents manually (Something like you'll pass a timestamp & keep docs only less than 10 mins & delete rest others) or do you want an automated process to delete docs after 10mins of being added - If yes - Check this :: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766763/how-to-create-ttl-index-on-long-timestamp-in-mongodb) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete it manually then I suggest the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library:

```
db.collection.deleteMany(
   {
      timestamp: { $lte: moment("2020-04-16T09:23:22.938+00:00").subtract(10, 'minutes').toDate() }
   }
)
```

But I assume the proper way would be a [TTL Index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/index.html):

```
db.collection.createIndex({ timestamp: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 * 60 } )
```